# The preimage of a Lebesgue measurable set under a measurable function need not be measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

I am reading measure theory from Royden, and I am stuck in some of them. I have this question:

> suppose  $E$ is  a measurable set and let $f: E \to \mathbb{R}$. Prove that : $f$ is measurable if and only if $f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable for any $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

I know this is not true if measurable means "Lebesgue measurable", can anyone give a counterexample in details ?

Comment: Since he knows it is not true, maybe "measurable" means "Lebesgue measurable".  So we need one of those examples of a measurable function $F$ and Lebesgue measurable set $A$ such that $F^{-1}(A)$ is not Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: exactly what I need

Comment: @Safeyya Malkawy : Can you precise with respect to which $\sigma$-algebras the function $f$ is measurable?

Comment: $f : E \to \mathbb R$ is "measurable" iff, for every $c \in \mathbb R$, the set $\{x : f(x)>c\}$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: I mean Lebesgue measurable functions ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pre-image of a measurable set A is always measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207040/pre-image-of-a-measurable-set-a-is-always-measurable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $C \subset [0,1]$ denote the Cantor set and let $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be the Cantor function.

The function $g(x) = f(x) + x$ has the property that $g : [0,1] \to [0,2]$ is strictly increasing, continuous, and maps the Cantor set to a set of positive measure. Thus $g(C)$ contains a nonmeasurable set $Z$, and $g^{-1}(Z) \subset C$ is measurable since $C$ has measure zero.

Now define $h = g^{-1}$. Then $h : [0,2] \to [0,1]$ is continuous and thus measurable, $g^{-1}(Z) \subset [0,1]$ is measurable, but $Z \subset [0,2]$ is not. Finally observe $h^{-1}(g^{-1}(Z)) = Z$.

Thus it is possible for $h$ to be measurable, $A$ to be measurable, but $h^{-1}(A)$ to be nonmeasurable.

Comment: thank you ...   but c in your example is Vitali's set not cantor  ,isn't it ? ? since [ 0,1] is measurable

Comment: No, $C$ is the Cantor set.

Comment: As Mr. P. has just shown, if your function maps sets of measure zero to sets of positive measure, then it cannot have this property. [Because sets of positive measure contain nonmeasurable sets.]  Now for some research: find out what are the necessary and sufficient conditions on a continuous function $f$ so that it maps measurable sets to measurable sets.

Answer (score -2):

What is your definition of measurability? Mine goes like this : a function $f : (X, \mathcal F) \to (Y, \mathcal G)$ is measurable if and only if $f^{-1}(\mathcal G)\subseteq \mathcal F$. At this point there are two things to do :

1. Know the definitions of all the objects involved in your question (Measurable spaces, $\sigma$-algebras, measurable functions, inverse images). Write them down explicitly, it helps. See what are the elements of the sets involved and the properties they satisfy.
2. Think for a bit. (We're doing mathematics after all!)

Hope that helps,

Comment: When the function $f$ is real-valued, the $\sigma$-algebra $\cal G$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, but saying $A \subset \mathbb R$ is measurable usually means that $A$ is an element of the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra. There is a bit more to this problem than checking definitions.

Comment: I know all of these definitions  I just need a counterexample I always have a problem in finding them . thank you

Comment: @Umberto P. : I rarely work with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra when dealing with real-valued functions... I assumed it was the Lebesgue one the whole time. But then again this was not specified in the question so I cannot know.